# Is there a way in Smarty to get the file extension of a string

Tags: smarty

Since we can get the file extension in php by using the explode function or in_array check.
Is there a way in Smarty to get the file extension of a string. 
But how can we get the file extension in tpl page using smarty?currently i am passing all the extension as an array and using the {foreach} to list in tpl file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php

    $smarty->assign('filename', 'foo\bar.txt');

?>
```

{* in your tpl *}

```
{$filename|pathinfo:$smarty.const.PATHINFO_EXTENSION}
```

{* you get 'txt' *}

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin I created just for that:

```
<?php
function smarty_modifier_file_extension($file)
{
    $bits = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = $bits?array_pop($bits):''; 
    return $ext;
}
```

Save it as modifier.file_extension.php in your smarty's plugins folder (or a custom plugins folder if you have any) and use it like this:

```
 {$filename|file_extension}
```